# Bokeh change quality export plot

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, png, bokeh

I am trying to export some grid into either png or svg but with svg option—as the doc states-the plots are exported as multiple files. So the only option is *png*. (For some reason if I use the toolbar, I only get the first plot and not the other).

But the quality of the *png* is terrible. Is there an option to set dpi or whatever? Even I you try to save [graphs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#userguide-quickstart) on the official documentation, you obtain poor quality.

I really like Bokeh and found it nicer to use that any other libs but this quality export is critical for me (publication purpose).

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you are running.

Comment: @MichaelHall well I will if you want but I use strictly the same two lines of the documentation

Comment: I was also referring to an example of the code to generate the plot so I can recreate the 'poor' quality `png` - basically an [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MichaelHall Again, no particular code. Anything. Try to save these [graphs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#userguide-quickstart) from the official doc. When zooming just a little the quality is poor.

Comment: I see what you mean. It looks like some of the elements render terribly (although the axes seem to be fine). Might have something to do with how glyphs are added to the canvas for the rendering. Might be worth opening an issue on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions of Bokeh the `export_png` accepts `width` and `height` parameters that you can set as arbitrarily large as you like, e.g:

```
export_png(p, "plot.png", width=2400, height=1000)
```

Comment: I guess this could be a way to mitigate this.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that Bokeh currently uses PhantomJS as the default "browser". It's possible that this is responsible for low DPI output. `export_png` also accepts an explicit Selenium webdriver argument. You could try with a Chrome or FF webdriver, but I think there may still some kinks to work out (please report any findings). At some point one of those (probably Chrome headless) will become the new default.

Comment: This does not work as expected since it does not scale the glyphs proportionately but rather changes the extend of the figure, making the glyphs and text just appear smaller. So if you scale width and height by a constant you get a different output image depending on the constant you choose.